# postgres sql update table from values in second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

The objective is up update table1 based on values in table2. Table1 is a master transaction level table with missing account level information, in this example the address field is incomplete, it is not fully populated. The information required to update the missing data is in table2.

The structure of table1 is:

```
account_num, name, address, record_detail_1, record_detail_2, ...
```

The structure of table2 is:

```
account_num, address
```

As an example the following query updates table1 successfully:

```
update table1 set address = '123 Elm ST' where account_num = '123456' and address is NULL;
```

The question is: How can the update query be extended to read values from table2 and update table 1.